# On "cosmic flux" units

Tags: units, cosmic-rays

I've trouble understanding the following graph, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray):
[image]

It's supposed to show the cosmic ray flux vs particle energy. I've never seen a "flux" written in these units...
Why ${GeV}^{-1}$?

Comment: Why not? This is a distribution over particle energy. That factor is just saying "per unit of energy".

Comment: Spectra are dN/dE which is per unit energy. But be aware that in astroparticle research, often that same information is shown multiplied by some E^(-2.7) or some such power law. That is because this spectrum is so extremely steep. So always check the vertical axis units first with those cosmic ray spectrum plots ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a differential flux.  If you wanted to know the total particle rate per unit area, per unit solid angle, per unit time, with units $\rm m^{-2}\,sr^{-1}\,s^{-1}$, you would have to choose an energy interval that you care about and integrate the curve in the figure.

Some authors would write a monstrous differential symbol rather than $F$, like

$$
F = \frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dA\ \mathrm d\Omega\ \mathrm dt\ \mathrm dE}
$$

to make explicit that the number of particles observed $N$ depends on your detector’s area $A$, its solid angle acceptance $\Omega$, your experiment’s running time $t$, and your choice of energy window.

The horizontal lines on the diagram are probably integrated over $4\pi$ steradians for all particle energies higher than the intersection of the horizontal line and the blue differential flux curve.